# MySQL: Select unique field and return all other columns as well + if specific column is not 0 - return that

Tags: mysql

I can't figure out how to get this done.
Basically I am making message system, I have this table:
[image]

Basically I am trying to print out threads, like every distinct msgfrom is a new thread. 
Thread should basically say:

> [(Sender Name) (Last Message (ORDER BY id DESC)) ([if at least one
>   message has msgread=0 then say You have unread messages])

I've tried this so far:

```
SELECT id, msgfrom, message, date, 
IF(msgread='0', 'unread', 'read') AS msr 
FROM pmessages WHERE msgto=$userId GROUP BY msgfrom
```

But that returns:

```
message from: Username (this is msgfrom 1)
read
message from: Username (this is msgfrom 2)
unread
```

Even though msgfrom1 has 1 unread message, it says read (I assume it takes first result). So in basic:

```
SELECT UNIQUE msgrom
ORDER BY id DESC
IF at least ONE msgread = 0
   return * + set msgread=0 (unread)
```

It's a bit hard to explain, sorry if it's a bit unclear.

Comment: There is no need to use `AS` in your query since there is only 1 table mentioned. Remove he if statement. Your query should return the results you required, please use it directly in phpMyAdmin and check the results you get

Comment: Should look like this: `"SELECT id, msgfrom, message, date FROM pmessages WHERE msgto=$userId GROUP BY msgfrom"`

Comment: @odedta it still returns same result as I mentioned in question. If using your code - it doesn't return if message was read or not.

Comment: Please explain exactly what data you're trying to pull from the table and how you want people to view it.

Comment: @odedta I am trying to get id, msgfrom, message, date AND msgread.
However - msgread must be either 0 or 1 which is based on already existing values.
If all msgread in database are 1, then return 1. ELSE if AT LEAST ONE msgread is 0, return msgread as 0

Comment: Just return all values into an object or an array and then use those IF statements. So you have a basic MySql query `SELECT id,msgfrom,message,date FROM pmessages`
Then use the IF statement for the returned values, `if(strcmp(arr['msgread'],'0') == 0) //do something`

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably GROUP your data together as you attempted in the first SQL.

If I understand you correctly, you want to differentiate the posts which are read and unread?

```
SELECT id
     , msgfrom
     , message
     , date
     , CASE WHEN msgread = 0 THEN 'unread' ELSE 'read' AS msgread
  FROM pmessages
 WHERE msgfrom IN ( SELECT DISTINCT msgfrom
                      FROM pmessages
                     WHERE msgto = ?
                  )
 ORDER BY msgfrom ASC
     , date DESC
```

Please make sure you use placeholders in your code (assuming PHP) rather than passing the variable in directly into the query, to prevent SQL Injection.

Let me know how you get on.